# Getting Linux Serial Console working on imx31

Tags: linux, console, serial-port

I have just ported uboot and the linux kernel to my imx31 based board. The kernel boots up because I can see the kernel messages in the ring buffer in ram, but I am not seeing and text on the serial port after ... decompressing kernel, done,  booting kernel"

I am passing "console=ttySMX0,115200" on the kernel arguement line, but I am not seeing the serial device being probed by the kernel (the serial driver is being registered, but no probe is happening).

I don't understand the relationship between the serial console name "ttySMX" and what the kernel expects.

I have built the kernel under openembedded with support for the LogicPD liteboard and Freescale ADS31 board, as these are closest to my board.

Any help much appreciated ... I have been trying to get this going for two weeks.

Answer (score 0):

Amongst other things need to have both CONFIG_SERIAL_IMX and CONFIG_SERIAL_IMX_CONSOLE selected in your kernel configuration.

It's possible these tags could have other names in your build.  In the one I looked at, they were referenced in driver/tty/serial/imx.c - if there is a different file that embodies the driver in your build, look for similar options in its source and in the Makefile in that directory.

Comment: Hi, I have both of those options set in my kernel config. The relevant file is driver/serial/imx31 and I am seeing the  imx_serial_init() function called which registers the device ... but nothing else called. Am I missing something?

Comment: Could you link to the source of your kernel tree?

Comment: Hi Chris,Not sure what you mean here. Do you mean where I got the source from, or do you want me to place it somewhere for you to look at. If the later, I do not have a web site available to do that.